# I am the One, The promised prince - Do I have to live with my real identity hidden?

Tags: super-powers, supernatural

Let be known that I am the one, that Super-Man-like hero, who recently came to know that I got some special abilities. I am something more than the normal human race and I can achieve tough things with a lot of ease and less effort.

I just recently came to know that I got these things in me. I am unaware of how far I can go. Maybe a stone will have an affect on me or not like Superman - I dont know. But I am doing some things beyond of what humans can think of. I just know this - I am something more than a human.

Now I decide to end crime. But, as the movies depict (most of them, except *Iron Man*), should I be worried about the revealing of my identity to the public and if yes - why should I?

Because

- they may think of me as a weapon, who may loose his control
- or fear that they may experiment on me by taking control of me?
- List goes on..

Is living with a double identity the only solution I am left with, or can I live normally, with the fan following  and also receiving criticism for my work?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *nobalG*! You mention that your character is like Super Man, but later you mention different movies by using Iron Man as an example. So which one is it? The guy who becomes weak when a certain stone comes near him and would be dead instantly if the bad guys found out where to find him when he sleeps, or the billionaire with the expensive toys and security measures? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Superheros are a stereotypical male fantasy for those that feel worthless in modern life. You are nobody, an office guy with sweaty armpits at day, but nobody knows that at night, you kick bottoms. You put on your costume and hunt criminals and get women. If you take down that double identity thing, you end up with a guy that needs to market his image, that needs to answer for his crimes, that might have some sort of boss (unless you no longer care about democracy and so on), you need to spend some time in the office and manage what you do and ... damn it! You are back where you started. See?

Comment: should I be worried about the revealing of my identity to the public and if yes - why should I? Well, YOU are a criminal. In most countries, citizens only are allowed to interfere in crimes in certain cases. You could be brought to courts for the injuries caused to criminals, for kidnapping them if you tie them up, etc.

Comment: @AlbertoYagos, there's a principle of "citizen's arrest" which allows ordinary people to take such actions

Comment: @Separatrix - do superheroes always follow this principle? From what I see in their depictions, even the best of them can be criminally prosecuted for their actions (although jury might want to fully exonerate them).

Comment: @Alexander, Spiderman does, most of the rest could be hauled up for use of excessive force or reckless endangerment.

Answer (score 7):

Consider a man called Harry Wales who wanted to be a soldier. Unfortunately he was born to wealth and fame and would be a danger to his unit if anyone found out he was there. A young man who wanted a normal life but will never be able to escape that fame. Perhaps his star will fade a little as his nephew and niece grow up but he will always be a prince.

The thing with the secret identity is that it gives a chance to have a normal life. Iron Man was already rich and famous, he was already a target for every nutter under the sun, he'd never had anything resembling a normal life. Being famous for another thing is not that great an issue, there's nothing to go back from. Spiderman, Superman and the others, they're not independently famous, as normal people they can still have normal lives.

The problem with letting the cat out of the bag is that you can never get it back in again. Once your secret identity is known, that's it, the end of anything resembling normality. No more nights on the town with the lads, no more quiet dinner dates in a restaurant. Everywhere you go you'll be recognised, called out to by strangers, ambushed for autographs or just ambushed and attacked.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that, with modern technologies, this double-identity can be kept for any extended period of time.

"Witness Protection Programs" are notoriously difficult and expensive to keep up.

There are, however, many good reasons to try.

- You are always more vulnerable in your "street cloths".
- You are bound to have a social life and you won't ever be sure about real intentions of anyone approaching you.
- You are bound to have ties and thus you can be threatened/blackmailed through them (none likes having his grandchild kidnapped... if you live enough to have one).
- You are bound to break (or, at very least, to bend) many laws in your crusade to "end the crime"; double identity shields you from endless lawsuits.
- Government *will* want to have a say in what you do.

I think you have better to try to lie low and hit the "crime" (I would like to have a meaningful and usable definition of that word) indirectly, making your work look like "bad luck" of the criminal (e.g.: puncture a tire of an escaping car).

Otherwise you've better to surrender to whatever Government Agency you like and have them use you as *they* please.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific on one part of Separatrix' answer: a secret identity protects not just yourself but also everyone you have relationships with. Maybe you don't care about having a normal life - who knows? Maybe stardom is ok for you, maybe you don't mind being considered a human weapon, maybe you can defend yourself against anything and everyone coming at you for whatever reason. This is a decision you can make for yourself. But your mom can't.

By being public with your superpowers you're implicating everybody else connected to you, your family, friends, partners, coworkers etc. They don't have the superpowers you do, so they're helpless against the level of threat you'll be facing and they'll be the first target of everyone who think they can't take you, but blackmailing you might just work out. As long as you're still psychologically mostly human you'll have a need for human relationships. Secrecy doesn't just let you go out for burgers, it lets you go on dates.